# Tag button for tags in Discussions disappears when the tag filter is open

Tags: bug, status-planned, discussions-space, high-contrast-mode

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the [discussions overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions)
   [image: The "Tags" button can be seen.]
2. Open the tag filter
   [image: The "Tags" button cannot be seen after clicking it.]

Additional information:

- Closing the tag filter shows the button gain.
- The button *is clickable* and physically there. The only signs of it when the filter is open is the background of the tag count and the fact that the cursor changes when over the invisible button.
- This happens only in high contrast modes.

Comment: Note: This is specific to high contrast mode (Light / Dark both).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks, I hadn't tried it in other themes.